# Programmically add multiple empty fields on a multiple value field/form

Tags: 7

In Drupal 7,  When you set a field "Number of values" to unlimited, it will show you 1 field on the creation page with an add more button.  How would one go about so it shows 5 empty fields on the creation page?

Answer (score 0):

Have tested this in Drupal 8 but I think it is the same for drupal 7.

```
if($form_id == 'node_MYCONTENTTYPE_form') {
  $item = $form['FIELD_MY_FIELD_NAME']['widget'][0];
  for ($n=1; $n<5; $n++) {
    if(!isset($form['FIELD_MY_FIELD_NAME']['widget'][$n])) {
      $form['FIELD_MY_FIELD_NAME']['widget'][$n] = $item;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Stef help, I figured it out for D7

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
  if ($form_id == 'MYNODE_node_form') {
    $item = $form['field_NAME'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0];
    // Add a minimum of 5 fields.
    for ($n=1; $n<5; $n++) {
    if(!isset($form['field_NAME'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$n])) {
      $form['field_NAME'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$n] = $item;
    }
  }
}
```

Now the only problem is it'll grab field 1, so if field 1 has a value in it, it'll get copied, to the 2nd, then 3rd, etc.  If I figure that out I will update my answer.  For now, I hope this helps others.